# Facebook graph api picture id returns false

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, image

We want to return information of a picture. When we put the picture id in the facebook graph api explorer, it returns 'false'. This picture, however, does exisist.

This is not the case with all pictures, most of the picture id's do return info.

This picture does work: https://graph.facebook.com/313969928665779?access_token=xxxxxxx (http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=313969928665779)

But this one doesn't: https://graph.facebook.com/3567929882847?access_token=xxxxxxx (http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3567929882847)

We use a valid access token. What can be the problem?

Comment: Who's picture is this? Maybe you don't have permissions to view this picture? For example: if I set a picture of mine to private, or only my friends can see it, then your app can't get info about it even if you have a valid access token.

Comment: This is a public picture, we do have permission to view this picture.

Comment: I see. Does this happen with just this photo or is it just an example of something that happens to you? Can you give me another example?

Comment: It happens only with this picture (http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3567929882847). this picture is posted on our wall, like many other pictures that do return info in the Graph Api Explorer. Only this picture returns 'false'. This picture is public, not deleted, 31 likes etc etc. Like all the other pictures, I can't see the difference.

Comment: Photo privacy settings depend on who uploads them, maybe who ever uploaded this specific image have very strict privacy settings that prevent your app of getting the photo data. You might want to file a [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) and see what the fb guys tell you.

Comment: As you can see here: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=3567929882847
This photo is shared with public.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the pic, but what you see on facebook itself is different than what facebook offer applications which interact with the graph. I do agree with you that the behavior is strange, at least they should give an error message that will explain what the problem is. As I said, you should file a bug report.

Comment: We have done that, you can find it here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/383933248292109

Comment: @FIA2008 : I having same issue, did you solve this ?

Comment: @VineeshTP I can't remember, it's around 2 years ago. Sorry.

Comment: @FIA2008 : ok, thnks :(